# ignore positive chat I'd telegram bot

Tags: telegram, php-telegram-bot

I have webhook a telegram bot for search data my a hosted
How can ignore positive chat I'd by bot I have a bot to search files from my hosted data And get link using telegram I want that bot just work in groups only If any person try to use it in personal chat it will not give reply means not search data and not give a link

Comment: '.', ',', ':', '!', '?', ';' ...?

Answer (score 0):

Every message has a chat field and each chat has a type see [telegram bot api](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api)

> Type of chat, can be either “private”, “group”, “supergroup” or
> “channel”

check if type of chat of message is equal to “group” or “supergroup” then do what you want.

In php can check like below

```
if($message->chat->type == "group")
  ...
```

Comment: yes,Please add code to your question, then I edit it and show you how exactly @LalitSachdeva

Answer (score -1):

Can you clear before using this command
if($message->chat->type == "group")
Need other commands in header
Or full command please